Repeated new accounts
Is there any automatic control in SE that removes or at least limits new accounts created repeatedly?
These are three different accounts on SpanishSE created within a day of each other:

And these are created a day later with the same username with the syllables exchanged:

By the way, the content of the questions is totally irrelevant and absurd. Personally I think they are for vandalizing the site

Repeat offenders can have their IP addresses blocked, along with various other countermeasures.

The issue is network-wide. Chem.SE: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/edits-by-anonymous-user-and-approved-by-community-bot | Phy.SE https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14841/reviewer-suggestion-take-note-of-who-is-proposing-edits-even-apparently-legit | ELL.SE: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6047/we-have-a-bad-case-of-socks-on-ell-please-help-update-4

"the content of the questions is totally irrelevant and absurd": why? I had a look at a few of them and they seem fine, even interesting, and are upvoted. I don't see a problem here, can you clarify what problem this is causing?

Personal opinion. Regarding the upvotes, I don't give them much importance knowing that there are three accounts that can belong to the same user, so the positive votes can also be from the same person. In any case, neither the content nor the votes are the essential issue of the question.

Stack Exchange allows its users to set up multiple accounts on one or more of their sites. The vast majority of these accounts will have different usernames, making it almost impossible to know (for example) if the user who answers a  question is the same person who submitted it in the first place. But there are –extremely rare– exceptions to the rule, when the holder of the secondary account is up front and informs visitors that they also have a main account.
As far as I am aware, there is no limit to the number of multiple accounts a user can create.  For each new account, the main account holder will devise a unique username because the user wants or needs to be anonymous (unrecognised).
So in the situation that the OP describes, "Cipolletti" is at least recognisable, be they registered or unregistered it doesn't matter. They are within their rights to create as many accounts as they need.

Some people seem to have more than 90 user accounts.. (posted in 2010)
Source: Why are people allowed to have multiple user accounts?


It is not a problem to have multiple accounts, as long as they aren't voting for each other and doing other sockpuppet-y things.  @Jeff Atwood (co-founder of Stack Exchange)
Source: What's the policy about having multiple user accounts?

Numerous reasons have been supplied over the years for justifying multiple accounts


Now I have two accounts, one which I use for work, the other which I use at home (reason I use two is that I don't trust logging into my personal Google account at work) @Haedrian
Source: Multiple Accounts - opening bounty on question




testing bugs that only show up at low rep levels
…answering questions on a tag that's new to you (ensuring voters vote for the answer, not the user)
…instances where posts being attributed to the primary account would be problematic (e.g. keeping hobbies private)   @Shog9
Source: How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?




…an account used for untrusted systems and testing. @Journeyman Geek
Source: How can I manage multiple work accounts with my personal Stack Exchange account?




To keep a low profile if you are female/a minority and fear harassment a la Kathy Sierra.
…for instance having an account for java questions and another for C questions because that helps you keep them organized.
You have an account that is associated with (or could be traced back to) your company and your question might compromise security or taint your brand's image. @lala
source: What's the policy about having multiple user accounts?




Specifically, as I'm here under my real name (used for my normal activities), I'll be at a bit of a disadvantage when it comes to discussing things where I need to hide who I work for. @Phil Lello
Source: Using multiple accounts (ethically)



Until "Cipolletti", ("Cipoletti", "Cipolate", "Tecipillo“) spams and disrupts the site, upvotes their own content and contributions, repeatedly posts gibberish, creates a new account to circumvent a suspension, displays anti-social tendencies (e.g. behaving like a troll) etc. their accounts are allowed to exist.

The accounts are unregistered (you can see that on the profile pages) - it could be that this is a user who clears browser cookies every day or something like that, and doesn't care about reputation or privileges (they're not voting - again, that's visible on their profile). They are not question-banned - most questions even have a positive score. I think it's unlikely to be a spam seed, just a user who interacts with the system / community in a non-typical way. (I haven't looked in detail at the contents of the questions yet, will do that later.)

They won't get q-banned because each account only asks one question anyway.

Correct, q-bans are per account. But with a positive question record it's hard to get q-banned either :)


Is there any automatic control in SE that removes or at least limits new accounts created repeatedly?

The answers in Are usernames required to be unique? indicates display names aren't required to be unique, but you can't pretend to be someone else.
For this part:

By the way, the content of the questions is totally irrelevant and absurd.

They might be spam seed posts.
On Super User this week there has been a number of new users posting gibberish. In line with the advice in What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work? I have been flagging gibberish posts from new users with a reputation of one as "rude or abusive".
Therefore, perhaps flagging is the way to deal with the problem on SpanishSE.

Ahh, you’re the guy from the SU cannery who’s been helping out :D Good answer. Spam seed is very relevant.

You can of course pretend to be an ordinary user and create something like 17 different accounts, give or take, each one with the same username. Please see my request for assistance on meta ELL, which was originally posted here but was later migrated.

Arguably, this is a feature of having unregistered accounts, not a bug. Behavior like this could even happen by accident, since regularly deleting cookies will remove any access to an unregistered account, with the only obvious option forward being to create a new account.
Disabling unregistered asking (and/or answering) makes it almost impossible for this to happen by accident (especially more than once), since the account has to be verified via email, and emails can't be duplicated like with unregistered users. Registration also slows down abusive account creation and may be helpful if moderators need to get involved, while not being a huge burden to legitimate users (who only need one account). It's an option worth considering.

Well, how is that done for a site? Who can do it?

@Lambie You can post on meta and if there's consensus a mod should bring it to CM attention (via [tag:status-review]). Mods can also ask CMs directly, without going to meta (see e.g. ELU) but that's obviously not applicable here.

I'm going to cut-and-paste the ELU one into the Spanish META and maybe some others.
