Can you please consider multi site behavior in automatic bans?
If I'm correctly understanding this answer, behavior and bans on one site do not automatically affect a user on other SE sites.
For the past few weeks, what appears to be a single person has been posting hundreds of unserious or nonsense posts with multiple sock puppet accounts. This individual appears to be taking advantage of this cross-site leniency to post more nonsense per account created, by posting to multiple sites with the same accounts.
Could we please slow this down by having some automatic measure(s) that consider cross site behavior?
This similar feature request from 2011 was marked answered in terms of migrations being blocked. That's great, but the kind of site vandalism I mentioned doesn't require question migration, so a migration block doesn't help.

Are you referring to this user: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405111/repeated-new-accounts? Or someone that is going by the name of "Asim Ahmed" (see the ELL.SE post in the meta link)?

@NilayGhosh Asim Ahmed, who I saw hit your site today. The user on Spanish didn't seem to be engaged in outright vandalism in my opinion, just (allegedly) talking to themselves and being a bit rude or overly familiar to others.

Hm, I see. That's very bad. He is a like a virus spreading across different sites. In Chem.SE, I saw two answers posted which was deleted already. 3 profiles of Asim's are there, one of which is suspended till end of 2025. Hopefully, this comes to notice to the staffs.

@NilayGhosh staff already aware about this case.

Red flags (spam, rude/abusive) have cross-site effects.
"hundreds of unserious or nonsense posts" seems to me like it would be described by:

Abuse of the system or community is everything that is created with the intention to harm them. This includes posts by users with no useful contributions to the site that contain no useful content at all

so it is appropriate to use rude/abusive flags when you encounter this content.
Of course this is not a complete fix for the issue: already posted content will still need to be handled (R/A flags are useful there, too!), and as a general rule automated systems will always have less scope than manual ones to reduce unintended effects of an automated ban.
